# Circle to Circle collision in Java

Tags: java, graphics, collision-detection

So I am doing circle to circle collision in java. I am aware that there are many similiar questions like mine on this website but my problem is unique from all of them. When I run my code, the circle's collide with each other once every 4 times. Meaning: 3 times they will go through without colliding with one another but one time they will collide. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public class Ball {
float x, y; // coordinates of ball rectangle
float xo, yo;
float vx = 2, vy = 2; // coordinates of velocity vector
Color colour; // ball colour
float d; // diameter of the ball or sizes of ball rectangle
Ellipse2D.Float circle;

// overloaded constructor
Ball(int x, int y, int vx, int vy, int d, Color colour) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.d = d;
    xo = x;
    yo = y;
    this.setColour(colour);
    this.setVelocity(vx, vy);
    circle = new Ellipse2D.Float(x, y, d, d);
}

public void setColour(Color colour) {
    this.colour = colour;
}

public void setVelocity(int vx, int vy) {
    this.vx = vx;
    this.vy = vy;
}

public void show(Graphics g) {
    ((Graphics2D) g).setPaint(colour);
    circle.setFrame(x, y, d, d);
    ((Graphics2D) g).fill(circle);
    xo = x;
    yo = y;
}

public void hide(Graphics g) {
    Color c = ((Graphics2D) g).getBackground();
    ((Graphics2D) g).setPaint(c);
    circle.setFrame(xo, yo, d, d);
    ((Graphics2D) g).fill(circle);
}

public void setPosition(float x, float y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public void move(int a, int b, int xh, int yh) {
    if (vy > 0) {
        if (y + d + vy - yh - b > 0) {
            y = yh + b - d;
            vy = -vy;
        } else
            y += vy;
    } else {
        if (y + vy <= b) {
            y = b;
            vy = -vy;
        } else
            y += vy;
    }
    if (vx > 0) {
        if (x + d + vx - xh - a > 0) {
            x = xh + a - d;
            vx = -vx;
        } else
            x += vx;
    } else {
        if (x + vx <= a) {
            x = a;
            vx = -vx;
        } else
            x += vx;
    }
}
```

The Collision Detector is in the class below

```
public class Game extends JFrame {
int ah, bh, xh, yh; // parameters of the rectangle frame
Color[] ColorAr = { Color.red, Color.blue, Color.pink, Color.green,
        Color.yellow, Color.magenta, Color.black, Color.orange, Color.gray,
        Color.cyan };
Ball b[];
int quantity = 4;

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    int i;
    ((Graphics2D) g).setPaint(Color.black);
    ((Graphics2D) g).drawRect(ah, bh, xh, yh);
    for (i = quantity - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        b[i].hide(g);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
        b[i].show(g);
    }
}

public void prepare() {
    int i;
    ah = 20;
    bh = 40;
    xh = 400;
    yh = 400;

    b = new Ball[quantity];

    for (i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
        b[i] = new Ball((int) (Math.random() * (300 - 1 + 1)) + 1, 100, 1,
                1, 26, ColorAr[(int) (Math.random() * 9)]);
    }
}

public void collision() {
    int radius = 13;
    int distance = 2 * radius;
    if (b[1].x + distance == b[0].x && b[1].y == b[0].y
            || b[1].x - distance == b[0].x && b[1].y == b[0].y) {
        b[1].vx = -b[1].vx;
        b[0].vx = -b[0].vx;
    }
}

public void run() {
    int i;
    while (true) {
        for (i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
            b[i].move(ah, bh, xh, yh);// move balls
        collision();
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000000; j++)
            ; // delay;
        // collision();
        repaint();
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Game frame = new Game();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    // frame.setBackground(Color.white);
    frame.setSize(450, 470);
    frame.prepare();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.run();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two circles:
First calculate the sum of lengths: `radius_1 + radius_2` (the first and the second circle).
Collision of two circles can be detected if you calculate the length of (imaginary) line between centers. If THAT `length <= radius_1 + radius_2`, two circles are colliding.

Comment: Thats what I did

Comment: Well, you didn't show the implementation. If it is `public void collision()` why don't you use `public boolean collision()`? Also, I think the Ball class should have this method declared. For example `public boolean collision(Ball otherBall)`

Comment: This works fine until the relative velocity is such that the change in position in one time step is greater than min(r1,r2), at which point you'll start to get "interesting" behavior.

Comment: @JimGarrison That's why I used `<=` instead of `==`. Or, maybe, you are right. I didn't try it. :)